# Interesting Playa bug requiring two closing tags of nested exp:playa:children tag pair

Tags: add-on, playa, bug

```
{exp:channel:entries}

    {exp:playa:children var_prefix="parent"}

        {parent:exp:playa:children var_prefix="child"}

        {/parent:exp:playa:children}
        {/parent:exp:playa:children}

    {/exp:playa:children}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

For whatever reason, I can get all the data I want inside all these loops **ONLY** if I have that second closing `{/parent:exp:playa:children}`. If I leave only one, which is what one might thing to be correct, it doesn't work properly. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try changing the var_prefix to something other than "parent" and "child", does that make a difference?

Comment: I'm not really using "parent"/"child" just used it for conversation's sake. Using product/faq.

Comment: I've just run into this issue - did you find a solution?

Comment: Hey @CreateSean, I don't remember what I ended up doing - it was quite some time ago (and of course I didn't use enough template code to know what to reference). If I had to guess, I probably ended up writing a method in a custom module to return the data I was looking for.